# Update Column: Case With Concat

Tags: sql, oracle

I am have a blank column, it is called column_blank. I want to concat two other columns (concat1, concat2) and based on the concat value, add a value into column_blank. I am extremely green and appreciate your help.

This is what I am thinking. I am not too confident about the DECLARE statement

```
DECLARE DIRECTION CONCAT := (CONCAT1, CONCAT2);

INSERT INTO 
MYDATA_EXTRACT_DATA.COLUMN_BLANK

SELECT

  CASE COLUMN_BLANK
    
    WHEN (DIRECTION) IS '123456', THEN ('654321'),
    WHEN (DIRECTION) IS '789101', THEN ('654321'),
    ELSE '000'
  
  END CASE 
  
  FROM MYDATA_EXTRACT_DATA
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just an ordinary `update` statement:

```
update mydata_extract_data set
  column_blank = case when concat1 || concat2 in ('123456', '789101') then '654321'
                      else '000'
                 end;
```